# Validation for registration form password

Tags: c#, webforms

I need to add to my existing validation  for password requirement while this works for minimum 8 characters. I need to expand it to included it to disallow special characters

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator Display = "Dynamic" ControlToValidate = 
"TextBox2" ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" ValidationExpression = "^[\s\S]
{8,}$" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Minimum 8 characters required.">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator
```

We would class the following as special characters

> -~@;.,*/%

Basically any no alpha numeric what would i need to add to above reg ex already there.
Many thanks for your assistance in advance.

**Edit 1**
I have got this far but I am unsure how to add the Min Max lengths

ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z0-9]*[^!@%~?:#$%^&*()0']"/>

Comment: Why on earth would you want to disallow perfectly reasonable characters from a password?

Comment: Its not my requirement its the companies requirment end the day have to do what is told. But I would agree with you

Comment: I said back to my boss their now to change it just to leave it 8 characters i think * though can give some bother with sql server if you let it be in a password

Comment: @David is their any chance you can help with the other part of question alpha numeric only and 8 characters min sometimes we dont like what we have to do what our bos says

Comment: I don't really have a regex handy for that, sorry.  But regarding the passwords themselves, *guaranteed* this company is very irresponsibly handling user passwords.  Restrictions like this indicate a very high possibility of (1) plain text passwords and (2) SQL injection.